# python list-within-dictionary convert to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I've converted a pandas.core.series.Series into a dictionary, with the data being the populations of the top 3 counties in each state, and there's an annoying indexing operator that I can't get rid of. The dictionary takes the form:

```
{('Alabama', 37): 660367.0, ('Alabama', 45): 353089.0,
 ('Alabama', 49): 415395.0, ('Alaska', 71): 298695.0,
 ('Alaska', 76): 99631.0, ('Alaska', 85): 101095.0,
 ('Arizona', 106): 4167947.0, ('Arizona', 109): 1010025.0,
 ('Arizona', 110): 406584.0, ('Arkansas', 118): 249672.0,
 ('Arkansas', 174): 392664.0, ('Arkansas', 186): 225477.0, ...
```

and I want to convert it to: `{('Alabama', 660367.0), ('Alabama', 353089.0), ...`
I'm really new to coding and hoping this is something really easy to fix. I can't figure out if there's a better way to convert the pandas series which avoids the additional data in the first place (I simply used `data=dict(data)`), or maybe a for loop through the dictionary...?

Comment: Share the contents of your dataframe by pasting data.head() so that we can illustrate options better for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily convert the output data with a list comprehension (or similar). If your data is in `data`, either of these lines will do what you actually asked and it depends on the data type you want:

```
out = [(key[0], value) for key, value in data.items()]
out = tuple((key[0], value) for key, value in data.items())
out = set((key[0], value) for key, value in data.items())
# In Python 2.7+ this is the same as the above
out = {(key[0], value) for key, value in data.items()}
```

But neither of them are a dictionary unlike the original. But that is because for a dictionary you need a unique key for each value, but the state name is not unique.

The basic idea is that they iterate over each item and use from it the state name (which is the first entry in the key, hence `key[0]`) and then add the population to it (just the `value`).

Now the one you have given, `{('Alabama', 660367.0), ('Alabama', 353089.0), …` is actually a set (at least that is the representation in Python 3, in Python 2 this is not a valid notation). Sets have no order and every entry is unique, so it'll save two counties with the same size in the same state as only one entry.

If you want to actually have a dictionary, you need to determine what the key should be and what the value for the key is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to convert this to what you want from the DataFrame object, but for a quick and dirty fix...

If you truly want it like this: `{('Alabama', 660367.0), ('Alabama', 353089.0), ... }`

You can do this (assuming python2.7):

(I'll assume we have a variable `d` that is the dictionary.)

`new_d = {(k[0], v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}`

`print new_d` =>

`{('Alabama', 353089.0),
 ('Alabama', 415395.0),
 ('Alabama', 660367.0),
 ('Alaska', 298695.0)}
  ...`

*This is actually a set.*